# GWT Remove button after clicking it

Tags: java, button, gwt

Have a problem - I would like to remove the button in GWT from panel after clicking it.

Something like this:

```
    VerticalPanel vp3 = new VerticalPanel();
    vp3.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

    final HorizontalPanel hp1 = new HorizontalPanel();
    hp1.setHorizontalAlignment(HasHorizontalAlignment.ALIGN_CENTER);

    final HTML fireCondText = new HTML("Fire conditions");
    fireCondText.setStyleName("h1");

    final HTML obscurity = new HTML("Obscurity:");
    obscurity.setStyleName("h3");

    final HTML statusObscurity = new HTML("NO");
    statusObscurity.setStyleName("no");
    if (statusObscurity.getHTML() == "YES") statusObscurity.setStyleName("yes");

    Button butObscurity = new Button(
            "Edit", new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    final Button butYes = new Button(
                            "YES", new ClickHandler() {
                                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                    statusObscurity.setHTML("YES");
                                    hp1.remove(butYes);
                                }
                            });
                    final Button butNo = new Button(
                            "YES", new ClickHandler() {
                                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                    statusObscurity.setHTML("NO");
                                    hp1.remove(butNo);
                                }
                            });
                    hp1.add(butYes);
                    hp1.add(butNo);                     
                }
            }
            );
    butObscurity.setStyleName("editButton");
```

But, obviously, eclipse underlines the remove method, giving me the error:

> The local variable butYes may not have been initialized

So, does anyone have any idea on how to do this? Or is there any way around?

I also thought about creating the counter, but this doesn't work also.

Sorry, if this is a stupid question, but I'm quite newbie in GWT.

P.S. Searched the site for similar question, found only disabling, but this is NOT what I need.

Comment: hp1 is a HorizontalPanel?

Comment: Try creating the button first to initialise it, then adding the click handler (two separate statements). This should prevent the Eclipse error, as butYes will now be initialised.

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty, yes, it is.

Comment: Declare your panel as final.

Comment: @GeorgeSalukvadze Can you post complete code?

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty, didn't help

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty, of course

Comment: @ShiladittyaChakraborty, see first post, updated it

Comment: @GeorgeSalukvadze Check my answer. That may be help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your button globally :

```
Button butYes = null;  
Button butNo = null;
```

Then modify your method :

```
            Button butObscurity = new Button(
                        "Edit", new ClickHandler() {
                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                 butYes = new Button(
                                        "YES", new ClickHandler() {
                                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                                statusObscurity.setHTML("YES");
                                                hp1.remove(butYes);
                                            }
                                        });
                                butNo = new Button(
                                        "YES", new ClickHandler() {
                                            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                                                statusObscurity.setHTML("NO");
                                                hp1.remove(butNo);
                                            }
                                        });
                                hp1.add(butYes);
                                hp1.add(butNo);                     
                            }
                        }
                        );
```

Comment: now I get error
    The final local variable butYes cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type, but the old error isn't displayed anymore (I added final before declaring buttons, as there was error that the variable must be final)

Comment: Have declare your button outside of the method?

Comment: nope, it's inside method fireCond, as I need to have it here, as I want to minimise code in onModuleLoad method

Comment: This code working if you declare your button outside of your method. i have already write in my answer declare your button globally then this code will be work.

Comment: alright, thx! and in general, would you recommend declaring panels and HTMLs globally as well or they should be in the method?

which is best way?

Comment: Otherwise you can create your button dynamically and write click handler that may be easy one.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a variable which could have not been initialized.
Therefore first create the button(s) and then attach the ClickListener(s):

```
final Button butYes = new Button("YES");
butYes.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
         statusObscurity.setHTML("YES");
         hp1.remove(butYes);
     }
});
```

Comment: this code didn't work, as the clickHandler is inside another button's clickHandler, but still thx!

Comment: @GeorgeSalukvadze why does it not work? Do you get a compiler or runtime error?

Answer (score 1):

The button will be the source of the `ClickEvent`, so:

```
@Override
public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
  // …
  hp1.remove((Widget) event.getSource());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
     statusObscurity.setHTML("YES");
     hp1.remove(butYes);
 }
```

When you click the button, program execute the code - hp1.remove(butYes). The program don't make sure the variable has value, so the IDE show the warning - The local variable butYes may not have been initialized.

If you just solve the warning, just initialize the variable.

The best way:

```
 public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
     statusObscurity.setHTML("YES");
     if (butYes != null) {
         hp1.remove(butYes);
     }
 }
```

if it was complicated sofeware, you check whether butYes is null. maybe you set the butYes is null somewhere.